# Account updates but an error occurs in the response

Tags: javascript, php, html

The account gets updated however I never get back the response "ok"
in the console. Instead what I get is Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ().

I can simply cannot spot what´s wrong. Please help me! I am desperate cause tomorrow I have an exam and I struggle with this bug for days.

My HTML:

```
 <!-- EDIT own account for USERS and ADMIN -->
    <div id="pageEditAccount" class="page popup">
      <div class="lblWrapper">  
        <h3>EDIT ACCOUNT</h3>
        <form class="form" id="frmEditAccount">
           <input type="hidden" name="txtEditAccountId" id="txtEditAccountId">   
           <input type="text" id="txtEditAccountEmailorPhoneNumber" name="txtEditAccountEmailorPhoneNumber" placeholder="Mobile number or Email">
           <input type="text" id="txtEditAccountName" name="txtEditAccountName" placeholder="Name">
           <input type="text" id="txtEditAccountLastName" name="txtEditAccountLastName" placeholder="Lastname"> 
           <input type="password" id="txtEditAccountPassword" name="txtEditAccountPassword" placeholder="Password">
           <img id="txtEditAccountImage" alt="AccountImage">
           <div class="lblFileUpload">
              <p>Select your picture:</p>
              <input type="file" name="fileUserImage">
            </div>
           <button type="button" class="btnForm" id="btnEditAccountForm">Update</button>
        </form>
        <h3 class="lblErrorMessage" id="lblEditAccountErrorMessage"></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My JAVASCRIPT:

```
 // sets value to the hidden field
 function setInputValue() {
   sUserId = sessionStorage.getItem( 'id' );   //ajUserDataFromServer.id;
   document.getElementById( "txtEditAccountId" ).value = sUserId;
  }

// Updates own account for ALL with POST

  btnEditAccountForm.addEventListener( "click", editOwnAccount );

  function editOwnAccount() {
      setInputValue();
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {

              var ajUserDataFromServer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
              console.log( "Response:" + ajUserDataFromServer );

              if ( ajUserDataFromServer.update == "ok" ) {

                  console.log( "ACCOUNT UPDATED" );
                  pageViewProducts.style.display = "flex";
                  //getajUserData(); //LOAD Users once again 
                  getjUserData(); //UPDATE the cahnge

              } else {

                  console.log( "UPDATE FAIL" );
                  pageEditAccount.style.display = "flex";
                  pageViewProducts.style.display = "none";
                  lblEditAccountErrorMessage.innerHTML = "";
                  var sEditAccountErrorMessage = "Updating Account Failed - Try again";
                  lblEditAccountErrorMessage.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', sEditAccountErrorMessage );

              }

          }
      }

      ajax.open( "POST", "api_edit_users.php", true );
      var jFrmEditAccount = new FormData( frmEditAccount );
      ajax.send( jFrmEditAccount );

  }
```

And my PHP API :

```
  <?php


    //GETTING FROM FILE:
    $sajUsers = file_get_contents('users.txt');
    $ajUsers = json_decode($sajUsers);

    //_________________________________________________________//


    // getting from the front end:
    $sUserId = $_POST['txtEditAccountId'];
    $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber = $_POST['txtEditAccountEmailorPhoneNumber'];
    $sNewUserName = $_POST['txtEditAccountName'];
    $sNewUserLastName = $_POST['txtEditAccountLastName'];
    $sNewUserPassword = $_POST['txtEditAccountPassword'];
    $sNewUserImageUrl = $sFolder.$sFileName;

 //_________________________________________________________//  


        $match_found = false;
        // getting it from the database
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $ajUsers ); $i++ ) {  

             if ( $sUserId  == $ajUsers[$i]->id ) {
                 //checks if the value of the id from the front-end is equal to the value in the array.
                  if ( fnCheckEmailFormat ( $sNewUserEmail ) ) { // call the function which checks if is a valid email
                     unset($ajUsers[$i]->phonenumber); // if there is a phonenumber key delete it
                     $ajUsers[$i]->email = $_POST['txtEditAccountEmailorPhoneNumber']; // then assign an email key to the object user
                  } 

                  else if ( fnCheckDigitFormat ( $sNewUserPhoneNumber ) ) {  // call the function which checks that it should only contain digits       
                              unset($ajUsers[$i]->email); //if there is an email key delete it                   
                              $ajUsers[$i]->phonenumber = $_POST['txtEditAccountEmailorPhoneNumber']; // then assign a phonenumber key to the object user
                      }

                  $ajUsers[$i]->name = $sNewUserName;
                  $ajUsers[$i]->lastname = $sNewUserLastName;
                  $ajUsers[$i]->password = $sNewUserPassword;
                  $ajUsers[$i]->image = $sNewUserImageUrl;
                  $match_found = true;
                  break;
            } 
        }

        //_________________________________________________________//


        if( $match_found ) {

            //PUTTING TO FILE:
            $sajNewUsers = json_encode( $ajUsers, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE  );
            file_put_contents('users.txt', $sajNewUsers);

            echo $sjResponse = '{"update":"ok"}';
            exit;
        }
        else {
                echo $sjResponse = '{"update":"error"}'; // it didnt work.
                exit;
             }

        //_________________________________________________________//


        function fnCheckEmailFormat ( $sNewUserEmail ){ //checks if the property is valid. Called in line 6.
            $sNewUserEmail = $_POST['txtEditAccountEmailorPhoneNumber'];
            if ( !filter_var( $sNewUserEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ){
                return false; // returns false if its not valid. Then it wont run the if.
            }
            return true; // else it will run the signin.
        }
        function fnCheckDigitFormat ( $sNewUserPhoneNumber ){ //checks if the property is valid. Called in line 6.
            $sNewUserPhoneNumber = $_POST['txtEditAccountEmailorPhoneNumber'];
            if ( !preg_match( "/^[0-99]+$/", $sNewUserPhoneNumber ) ){
                return false; // returns false if its not valid. Then it wont run the if.
            }
            return true; // else it will run the signin.
        }


        ?>
```

Now I also know that the bug is in the following code :
  cause if I remove it account updates successfully.

```
if ( fnCheckEmailFormat ( $sNewUserEmail ) ) {
             unset($ajUsers[$i]->phonenumber);// call the function which checks if is a valid email
             $ajUsers[$i]->email = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber; // then assign an email key to the object user
          } 
          else if ( fnCheckDigitFormat ( $sNewUserPhoneNumber ) ) {  /*call the function which checks that it should only*/             unset($ajUsers[$i]->email);                                       //contain digits
                  $ajUsers[$i]->phonenumber = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber; // then assign a phonenumber key to the object user
          }
```

Comment: Put a `debugger` in your JavaScript function `editOwnAccount` right before this line `if ( ajUserDataFromServer.update == "ok" )`. This will allow you to check the value of `ajUserDataFromServer.update` at that point - work backwards from there.

Comment: `[0-99]` is the same as `[0-9]`. The `+` allows more numbers, if you are trying to require the number be `0` or greater it can't be done this way, `0000` is valid here. Try `console.log(ajUserDataFromServer.update)` to see what value you get back.

Comment: Your PHP code is a mess. You should minimize the example as much as possible. This makes it easier for us to track down the actual mistake.

Comment: I can´t minify it more then this.